# Android Java @ Не пишется запись в базу

Tags: java, android, sql

Индусы индусами - пропали, но приложение готово.
Однако решил добавить недостающие поля в профиль.

в userDTO увидел, что есть bank_name
Он же используется и в API calls - как bank_name

Сл-но по аналогии как другие поля начал заполнять:

Const.java

```
String BANK_NAME = "bank_name";
```

Дальше
UserDTO.java

```
 public String getbank_name() {
        return bank_name;
    }

    public void setbank_name(String bank_name) {
        this.bank_name = bank_name;
    }
```

Дальше в ProfileSetting.java

```
private CustomEditText etName, etEmail, **etBank_name**, etMobile, etGender, etHomeAddress, etOfficeAddress;
```

и еще один

```
private CustomEditText etNameD, etEmailD, **etBank_nameD**, etMobileD, etOldPassD, etNewPassD, etConfrimPassD, etHomeAddressD, etOfficeAddressD;
```

там-же , но в методе setUiAction

```
 public void setUiAction(View v) {
        etBank_name = v.findViewById(R.id.etBank_name);
```

В методе showData()

```
etBank_name.setText(userDTO.getbank_name());
```

и в методе     public void dialogPersonalProfile() {

```
etBank_nameD = (CustomEditText) dialog_profile.findViewById(R.id.etBank_nameD);
etBank_nameD.setText(userDTO.getbank_name());
```

в dialog_personal_info.xml

```
<com.easyjob.meistars.utils.CustomEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etBank_nameD"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Something"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="" />
```

и в activity_profile_setting.xml

```
<com.easyjob.meistars.utils.CustomEditText
                        android:id="@+id/etBank_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:editable="false"
                        android:hint="Something2"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="" />
                    </com.easyjob.meistars.utils.InputFieldView>
```

В Webservices.php
Уже было написано

```
 public function editPersonalInfo()
    {
        $bank_name = $this->input->post('bank_name', TRUE);
```

и чуть ниже

```
$data['bank_name']=isset($bank_name) ? $bank_name: $checkUser->bank_name;
```

В приложении поле bank_name появилось, вписать туда могу, сохранить могу

После сохранения запись не идет в SQL.

Я делал по аналогии 1в1 с другими полями, вроде ничего не пропустил ничего не забыл.

В чем может быть проблема?

Спасибо всем за совет!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я тупица :)
в методе

public void onClick(View v)

забыл добавить

```
params.put(Consts.BANK_NAME, ProjectUtils.getEditTextValue(etBank_nameD));
```

Все работает.

@pavloff, спасибо благодаря Вам (по ссылке зашел на другую ссылку и увидел свой косяк)